# Is there a way to get discarded bit from shift_left/right or should I do it manually?

Tags: vhdl

Using VHDL 2008 and writing an ALU. Currently using `shift_left` and `shift_right` to perform logical shift operations but they discard the MSB and LSB respectively. I want to assign those discarded bits to the Carry flag. Is there any way to do so from these two functions? Or do I need to manually implement shifting so I can have access to the MSB and LSB?

Comment: Provide a [mcve], You could use concatenation and aggregate assignment, e.g. `(carry, sum) <= shift_left(data_value & '0', count);` preserving the use of the two functions. This is dependent on -2008 aggregate rules.

Comment: @user16145658 after the `shift_left` operation, the MSB - which is the last bit to be shifted out - would be discarded. Say `data_value = 01101` and that `count = 3`. The last bit to be shifted out in this case would be the third bit from the left (1) but after the shift operation, that bit is just lost, and the result would be `01000 0`

Comment: I was just coming in to fix this having had enough of mowing the lawn. `(carry, sum) <= shift_left('0' & data_value, count);` And it's the left most bits that gets discarded (there aren't any 'shifted out bits). So what does all this imply for shift_right as far as which end of the concatenation the data value is on and which end of the aggregate assignment target has a 'carry'?

Comment: @user16145658 how does the expression above assign the msb to the carry, say, for `count=1`? doesn't `shift_left` take precedence? I think I see it but not sure: by extending it with '0', `data_value` now has a msb which server as a placeholder for the discarded bit, and after that, shifting is done, which moves the previous msb to the new msb location. So say `101101` is conc'd with `0` and becomes `0101101`; then after one shift, it becomes `1011010`, and the msb of that is assigned to carry, and the rest to sum. Is this correct?

Comment: *So say 101101 is conc'd with 0 and becomes 0101101; then after one shift, it becomes 1011010, and the msb of that is assigned to carry, and the rest to sum. Is this correct?* After a shift of 1 to the left.

Answer (score 2):

Found a quick solution. I mapped the input signal - the one being shifted, which is 32bit wide - to a new signal which is 33bit wide. I then shifted the 33bit signal instead of the input signal to save the discarded bit and assign it to Carry.

EDIT: even better solution; determine beforehand which one's the last bit to be shifted out, and assign that to the carry flag. Then do the shift operations. This assigns the last bit to be shifted out, to the carry, before it's discarded and lost for good

Answer (score 2):

You can use the aggregate notation:

```vhdl
(carry, a) <= a & '0'; -- shift left
(a, carry) <= '0' & a; -- shift right
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know this was a thing - that's very handy; thank you!

Comment: This is one time I wish I could give the solution two up arrows rather than just one.   One for using concatenation as it concisely specifies what is going on (and works for more interesting solutions - like shifting a single dimensional array whose elements are arrays) and another for using the aggregate on the LHS.

Answer (score 0):

In sequential logic, you can assign the carry and shifted register at the same time:

```
-- Shift Left
data  <= shift_left(data, 1);
carry <= data(data'high);

-- Shift Right
data  <= shift_right(data, 1);
carry <= data(0);
```

Comment: The `data'high` wouldn't be the last bit shifted out in this case; it would be the next bit to be shifted out. So after one shift, the msb (in left shift) would be discarded and there is no way to access it after the shift operation

Comment: This solution assumes that data is 7 downto 0.  If you want to be correct independent of the range, use data'left instead of data'high and data'right instead of data(0).